# how to send invites to uninvited friends in facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using this code to invite friends in my facebook application

```
$app_id = "000000000000000000000";
$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/applicationname/";
$message = "join me in this app.";
$requests_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
            . "&message=" . $message;

     if (empty($_REQUEST["request_ids"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $requests_url . "'</script>");
```

every time the user call this page he can see all his friends
i need to view only the UNinvited friends.
how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better method would be to use the [javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You can use that to render a facebook popup with the share dialog inside...

With regard to your question, you can use filters for the `apprequest` method as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). You are looking for the `app_non_users` filter.

[EDIT]
If you want to filter even more - ie. don't list friends that have already been invited (but not yet accepted), you'll have to read each `request_id` generated and store the invited users facebook UID and place them in the `exclude_ids` filter. This method could be further optimized by using the javascript sdk and `FB.ui()` method, posting the generated `request_ids` using AJAX, reading the `request_id` server-side and returning the users UID to be added to a javascript array in order to be used in the `exclude_ids` filter for subsequent `FB.ui()` invite calls...